# Does changing a Oracle database charset from US7ASCII to AL32UTF8 "double" the database size?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

We are having some issue inserting Arabic and Hebrew text into an Oracle database. The character set of the Oracle 11g database is US7ASCII. Does altering the database's charset to AL32UTF8 immediately double the size of the database?

Comment: No, the space requirement for AL32UTF8 you have to take into account is only for the CHAR/VARCHAR values.

Comment: If your old character set is `US7ASCII` and you switch to `AL32UTF8` then the size stays the same, because US7ASCII can store only ASCII characters 0-127 (that's where the name comes from). Characters 0-127 are exactly the same in ASCII as in UTF-8, thus the size stays the same unless to insert any new data to you database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit if you make your comment into an answer, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you're asking...

In order to encode an Arabic or Hebrew character, the UTF-8 encoding uses two bytes.  So, for example, a `VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)` would be large enough to store 5 Hebrew characters and a `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)` would need 20 bytes of storage in order to store 10 Arabic characters.  Of course, if some of your data uses the Latin alphabet as well, which only require one byte of storage per character, or if some of the characters come from other Unicode planes (certain mathematical symbols, for example, emoji, etc.) that require three or four bytes of storage, then the question of "how many bytes do I need for a `VARCHAR(10 CHAR)`" or "how many characters can I store in a `VARCHAR(10 BYTE)`" get a bit more complicated.

Whether this "doubles the size of the database" depends on your perspective.  First, obviously, the character set has no impact on non-character data types.  Data stored in a `NUMBER` or a `DATE` column requires exactly the same amount of space regardless of the database character set.  Ignoring that, however, a comparison like "doubling" requires you to compare something to a baseline and that gets a bit tricky.  There is no baseline where you are going to (correctly) store Arabic and Hebrew in a US7ASCII database using a single byte of storage per character so it's not accurate to say that storing the data in an AL32UTF8 database doubles the storage requirements of string columns.  You could talk about a baseline where you're using a single-byte Hebrew character set like ISO 8859-8 but then you couldn't store Arabic data (or vice-versa if you were using a single-byte Arabic character set like ISO 8859-6).  You could potentially talk about a baseline where you have an incorrect NLS configuration where the database character set is US7ASCII but applications bypass character set conversion and insert data from multiple different single-byte character sets but then you're comparing the storage requirements for a correct, supported configuration against the storage requirements for an incorrect, unsupported, and highly bespoke configuration.

Comment: I was trying to understand if changing the charset immediately changes he database size. It sounds like the database size stays the same even with a charset change.